# get div#areaToPrint as an IMAGE/SCREENSHOT and print with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, printing

```
<div id="areaToPrint">
...
</div>
<script>
// how to get #areaToPrint as an image/screenshot and print it,
// because I don't have to worry about using css to reformat the area
</script>
```

real life context: print shopping order for customer

Answer (score 0):

More details would be nice, but I think I get what you are asking. If your goal is to insert text, you could use javascript:

```
document.getElementById('areaToPrint').innerHTML += 'Content to print';
```